# Why cannot it get iterator as reference in c++?

Tags: c++

I am learning c++.
I have learned referencing allow us to avoid copying.
So I tried to get an iterator of a vector as reference to overwrite its elements.

```
// simplified function
std::vector<int>::iterator& GetIterator(std::vector<int>& vec) {
    return vec.begin();  // compiler said that here is an error.
}
```

But compiler give me an error message and suggests to use const reference.
I would not like to use const.
Why cannot it get non-const reference?
Or how to avoid copying of iterator?
Thank you very much.

Comment: `vec.begin()` returns by value. So think about what that reference would refer to.

Comment: What is the exact error message you get?

Comment: Why do you want to avoid copying an iterator?

Comment: You can have references to iterators, but in most cases iterators are trivial structures that can easily be copied. And returning by value usually causes the compiler to *elide* the copying anyway. Search for and read more about *copy elision* and *return value optimization*.

Comment: `vector:begin()` is also overloaded, and the two overload have different return types (`iterator` and `const_iterator`).  The two are not interchangeable.   In C++11, there is also `std::begin()`.

Comment: @Rome_Leader : error message was following,     invalid initialization of non-const reference of type ‘std::vector<int>::iterator& {aka __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int> >&}’ from an rvalue of type ‘std::vector<int>::iterator {aka __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int> >}

Comment: @melpomene : I supposed that it is some cost when the vector has huge elements. However I don't know how much cost it takes. Now I am not sure I should care of the cost.

Comment: @mora For a vector, I'd expect the cost of an iterator to be exactly the same as the cost of a reference.

Comment: At this point im your C++ career, don't touch references except in function parameters. In particular, don't return references from functions, ever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can sometimes use a reference to avoid a copy - but here you need a copy. The result of `vec.begin()` is a temporary which ceases to exist when your function returns. If you want the value outside the function - and you do - then a copy is needed. (If you succeeded in forming a reference here it would be a "dangling reference", which is not a good thing.)

And in any case a lot of types are designed to be copied efficiently, and iterators are amongst those. And in fact the compiler can often avoid the copy for you, without you having to do any work at all - and this is one of those cases.

So the code without the reference is easier, correct, and already optimal.

Answer (score 1):

`vec.begin();` return a temporary object and is r-value. You can't bind a l-value reference to a r-value. After returning from `GetIterator` function, that temporary object will be destroyed and your reference will be dangled.

Return by value (`std::vector<int>::iterator`) instead of reference. `Iterator`s are designed to be copyable and cheap to copy. Also compilers use *Return value optimization* to avoid cost of coping objects.

Comment: Thank you for telling me why my code was wrong and how to do. Your instruction was clear and sharp.

Comment: @MRB *return a temporary object and is r-value reference*. It's not a rvalue reference, it is just a rvalue.

Answer (score 0):

**correct code**

```
std::vector<int>::iterator GetIterator(std::vector<int>& vec) {
    return vec.begin();  // compiler said that here is an error.
}
```

your `&` is extra.

The iterator is like `int*` and gets a **address**.
And `std::vector< type >::iterator` is like that.
So the `vector.begin()` is like `&int` so you can not bind it to `iterator&`